# Excel automagically insert formula

Tags: excel

I came across this excel files (xlsx) so there is no VBA involved, no table, no name. But columns C is updated with formula "automagically" when I insert a number into column B. I checked the name manager, there is no name. I would like to know how can I achieve this kind of functionality. Have anyone come across something like this?

P.S: When I copy Range A2:C13 and paste to a different files. The magic still works!

Screenshot in Excel 2016

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So, you go to `File`>`Options`>`Advanced` and tick the box that says:

> Extend data range formats and formul̲as

Comment: I'm using `Excel 2016`, what is your version? Plus your calculations should be set to `Automatic`

Comment: I'm using Excel 2016 too. And Formula > Calculation Options is set to `Automatic`

Comment: I tried your solution and it works fine for me: (1) create new Excel file (2) enter the data as shown above with the formula `=B2-A2` in column `C`. (3) with that advanced option set the formula is copied down and when I un-check that advanced option the formula from column `C` is not copied down. So, *(+1)* from my side (Excel 2016 Pro, Windows 7 64-bit).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got this one. Simply add 4 or 5 subsequence row with formula in column B and C. And continue continue to enter data in column B like this GIF:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I manage to have this behavior by having the formula defined on all the cells of the column* with an "`IF(NOT(ISBLANK(c); <your formula>; "")`" condition on the input cell:

- e.g. you enter this in <kbd>C1</kbd>

  ```
  =IF(NOT(ISBLANK(B1)); B1/(1+B1);"")
  ```
- you click and drag the formula like you know how;
- Et voila

*)(or as many as necessary, since it could be a little "heavy" for Excel to have the formula 1048576 times, nearly for nothing)

Hope it helps